# Как скрыть один UserControl и открыть другой в главной форме

Tags: c#, winforms

Как скрыть один UserControl и открыть другой в главной форме потому что visible, hide меня как то не спасают, их как будто и не существует

Comment: Я ничего не понял.

Comment: хахах, у меня есть одна главная форма, на ней 2 usercontrol мне нужно что бы один скрылся а другой показался поверх первого usercontrol, как будто переход между окнами

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15205787/6808809

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
userControl1.Visible = false;
userControl2.Visible = true;
```

Comment: да, я пробывал, но не помню почему не получилось, в любом случае большое спасибо, а ещё я нашёл такую команду - userControl1.BringToFront();, она тоже работает